# Looking for VSC HTML intellisense extension

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am looking for this extension in VSC in which when you type `div.container` and press `tab` it writes out `<div class="container">...</div>`

I've seen it on a LinkedIn post but couldn't find it anywhere yet and I'm sure a lot of you are using it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an Emmet expansion, and it's [built right in to VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet), *no extension required.*